# How to create print dialog in tkinter application

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, winapi, printing

Is there a way to invoke a standard Windows print dialog from **tkinter/Python 3.9**? The way I currently have this implemented is through a separate Python script (**print_mgr**) that uses PyQt5 (e.g., dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()). I compile the print_mgr script to a .exe and then use a subprocess function to call the print_mgr, passing it the file (file_name) to be printed. print_mgr presents the print dialog and the user can select the printer, options/preferences/etc, and then print the file.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([str(Path(sys.executable).parent) + '\\qrfe_print_mgr.exe', file_name])
```

This works fine, but is a little more complicated than I would prefer.

Is there a way to invoke a **WIN32API** call to open a print dialog? I've looked at using **mshtml.dll** and can actually get it to work with the following:

```
import win32api

file='C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\TestFiles\\print_test.text'
filepath = "C:\\windows\\system32\\mshtml.dll,PrintHTML " + '"' + file + '"'
win32api.ShellExecute(0, None, "rundll32.exe", filepath, None, 1)
```

But this an unsupported workaround and it does other things such as adding page numbers and url at bottom of the page.

Or maybe there's another way to solve this problem other than using WIN32API calls.

So I'm curious if anybody has any potential solutions to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Well, you _might_ be able to use the `win32print` module. I know that you can print things with it, but I don't think it has a print dialog (that's just judging by what I've found on Stack Overflow; I don't use Windows, so I don't know for sure). And designing your own print dialog to work with `win32print` wouldn't be much simpler than what you've already got...

Comment: @SylvesterKruin - thanks!